# how to utilize HikariCP with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hikaricp

When I used `Hibernate` itself, I could've done something like `Main.getSession().get(User.class, 1);` where `getSession()` would call `openSession()` from the session factory. but how can I do the same with `HikariDataSource`? Wiki mentioned something about `HikariConnectionProvider` but no example was given.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    if (dbUrl == null || dbUrl.isEmpty()) {
        return new HikariDataSource();
    } else {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want Hibernate to use connection pool provided by `Hikari`. If that is the case, then SessionFactory has a method `setDataSourc(...)`

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    // ...
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

When you open a session, a connection will be borrowed from Hikari pool.